# Word problem with $p$

Tags: problem-solving

In the year 2000, there are $p$ penguins. After $t$ years, the number of penguins is given by $$ 2500 \times 1.02^t$$
Calculate the number of penguins in the year $2000$.

I tried to substitute random values for $t$ to get a general pattern but I couldn't get an answer so please help.

Comment: If this is is true for all integer numbers $ t $, then take $ t=0 $ to get the number of penguins in the year $2000 $.

Comment: Just remember that $x^0=1$ ! You will need to use this zillions of times in your life ! Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, t=0, as there no years have passed since the year 2000. The answer is therefore 2500.